# Fail to operate SyncFolderHierarchy to archivemsgfolderroot

Tags: exchangewebservices

Approximately after 2/22 one of my archive mailbox SyncFolderHierarchy started to encounter this error, but remains work fine.

Is is possible to indicate server failure or some critical server update?

Thanks for help, request, response and headers are enclosed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/syncfolderhierarchy-operation

Request:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
    <soap:Header>
        <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013"/>
        <t:ExchangeImpersonation>
            <t:ConnectingSID>
                <t:PrincipalName>xxx@domain.com</t:PrincipalName>
            </t:ConnectingSID>
        </t:ExchangeImpersonation>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <m:SyncFolderHierarchy xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
            <m:FolderShape>
                <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
            </m:FolderShape>
            <m:SyncFolderId>
                <t:FolderId Id="AAMkAGI2YWI3NDQyLTYyODYtNGY0Zi04YjdiLTdkODhhYzIyZGI1ZAAuAAAAAADhRroG0XH/RKMERX2rvkf2AQBbW0SX+peLTr6oeV2++/0xAAAAAAEJAAA="/>
            </m:SyncFolderId>
            <m:SyncState></m:SyncState>
        </m:SyncFolderHierarchy>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Response & header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="20" MajorBuildNumber="3912" MinorBuildNumber="25" Version="V2018_01_08" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <m:SyncFolderHierarchyResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
            <m:ResponseMessages>
                <m:SyncFolderHierarchyResponseMessage ResponseClass="Error">
                    <m:MessageText>The mailbox operation failed.</m:MessageText>
                    <m:ResponseCode>ErrorInternalServerError</m:ResponseCode>
                    <m:DescriptiveLinkKey>0</m:DescriptiveLinkKey>
                    <m:SyncState/>
                    <m:IncludesLastFolderInRange>true</m:IncludesLastFolderInRange>
                </m:SyncFolderHierarchyResponseMessage>
            </m:ResponseMessages>
        </m:SyncFolderHierarchyResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

cache-control →private
content-encoding →gzip
content-type →text/xml; charset=utf-8
date →Fri, 05 Mar 2021 09:51:41 GMT
request-id →fd1fd1c5-5d03-456c-b947-e1005093f8df
server →Microsoft-IIS/10.0
transfer-encoding →chunked
vary →Accept-Encoding
x-aspnet-version →4.0.30319
x-backendhttpstatus →200, 200
x-beserver →CH2PR13MB3896
x-besku →WCS6
x-calculatedbetarget →CH2PR13MB3896.namprd13.prod.outlook.com
x-calculatedfetarget →CH0PR03CU010.internal.outlook.com
x-diaginfo →CH2PR13MB3896
x-ewshandler →SyncFolderHierarchy
x-feproxyinfo →CH0PR03CA0289.NAMPRD03.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
x-feserver →CH0PR03CA0289, HK2PR04CA0044
x-ms-appid →28c81f84-52e5-48eb-bd8d-e6e10ba7838c
x-powered-by →ASP.NET
x-proxy-backendserverstatus →200
x-proxy-routingcorrectness →1
x-rum-validated →1
```